# Unity - C# - NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, behavior-tree

**EDIT**

My question is different (I think..) because the last image allows me to set a GameObject to the Communication Message and Communication Message. BUT, on play, it immediately resets to None (Text) and None (Button). I don't know why this happens or how to solve this!

---

I am aware this question is widely covered but still I cannot solve this. I hope someone has a solution for me.

**What I have**

I am working with **Behavior Designer**, an asset for Unity. I'm making Behavior Trees and the problem occurred when using a [behavior tree reference](http://www.opsive.com/assets/BehaviorDesigner/documentation.php?id=53).

First, I had my Behavior Tree like this:

[image: Behavior Tree - Search door]

It searches the front door. If it is found, it will move towards it and communicate with the human playing the game.

**This worked before,** but now I put this behavior tree in a Behavior Tree Reference, like this:

[image: Behavior Tree Reference]

When I double click the reference, the first image shows. BUT, where it goes wrong, is this:

[image: Human Instructions]

**Problem**

This is the human instructions node in the first picture. It doesn't load the communication message and communication button. When I load the corresponding button, it immediately resets on playing the scenario. **This happened when I loaded this behavior in the Behavior Tree Reference**, and the problem didn't occur when I played this from the original tree self.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
HumanInstructions.CommunicationElements (Boolean activeOrNot) (at Assets/HumanInstructions.cs:54)
HumanInstructions.OnAwake () (at Assets/HumanInstructions.cs:19)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.BehaviorManager.EnableBehavior (BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Behavior behavior)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Behavior.EnableBehavior ()
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Behavior.Start ()
```

**Any ideas what could cause this and how to solve this?**

**The code from HumanInstructions**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using BehaviorDesigner.Runtime;
using BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Tasks;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

public class HumanInstructions : Action
{
    public string humanInstructionsText; // The string in inspector that shows up on-screen for the human operator to communicate with UGV.
    public string messageToConsole; // Print this message to console when the action is performed SUCCESSFUL.
    public string textOnButton; // See inspector in Behavior Designer. Is used as text on button.
    public Text CommunicationMessage;
    public Button CommunicationButton;
    bool boolClicked; // Is false; when the button is clicked, it will turn TRUE, calling the IF function, returning Taskstatus SUCCESS.


    public override void OnAwake ()
    {
        CommunicationElements (false);
    }

    public override void OnStart ()
    {
        boolClicked = false;
        CommunicationElements (false);
        CommunicationButton.onClick.AddListener (ButtonClicked);
    }

    public override TaskStatus OnUpdate ()
    {
        CommunicationMessage.text = humanInstructionsText;
        CommunicationButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = textOnButton;
        CommunicationElements (true); // The communication elements are VISIBLE on screen.
        TriggerStatusCameraView (false);
        if (boolClicked == true) { // this IF function is active when the button is clicked. See ButtonClicked () function.
            CommunicationElements (false); // Removes the communication elements from screen.
            TriggerStatusCameraView (true);
            return TaskStatus.Success;
        } else {
            return TaskStatus.Running;
        }
    }

    // The following function is called when the CommunicationButton is clicked on screen.
    void ButtonClicked ()
    {
        boolClicked = true; // Changes the value to true, so it will trigger the IF function in OnUpdate ();
        Debug.Log (messageToConsole); // Sends this message to the console.
    }

    // The following function can be called upon and turn all UI elements (such as text, buttons or images) ACTIVE or not.
    void CommunicationElements (bool activeOrNot)
    {
        CommunicationButton.gameObject.SetActive (activeOrNot);
        CommunicationMessage.gameObject.SetActive (activeOrNot);
    }

    // The following code will DISABLE camera control if the communication screen is active for the human operator
    void TriggerStatusCameraView(bool activeOrNot)
    {
        GameObject.Find ("FPSController").GetComponent<RigidbodyFirstPersonController_custom> ().enabled = activeOrNot;
    }
}
```

Comment: just a guess: if you make a prefab and reference its member to scene objects, and then try to instantiate from that prefab, then the reference links will be broken. maybe something related to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was simple. Thanks for looking into this.

```
Text CommunicationMessage = GameObject.Find("CrazyMsg").GetComponent<Text>();
Button CommunicationButton = GameObject.Find("MissionButton").GetComponent<Button>();
```